Lateral select from single data table
I have a table which is defined as
Datum, Name, weight

This is populate with:
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, Bob A, 90
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, Bob B, 120
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, Bob C, 90
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, Bob A, 100

I am looking for the code to present that back as:
Date, Bob A, Bob B, Bob Bob C
------------------------------
2024-01-01 18:00, 90, Null, Null
2024-01-01 19:00, Null, Null, 110
2024-01-01 19:30, Null, 120, Null




Datum
Bob A
Bob B
Bob C




2024-01-01 18:00
90




2024-01-01 18:00

120



2024-01-01 19:30


90


2024-02-01 08:00
80





What I am looking for is to put the column details into a table of columns just containing the name data.

Data consistency in your question would help with clarity. Your source data does not match your results.  And should weights taken at the same time appear on the same result row?

If you know all of the possible Name values ahead of time, you can use a PIVOT. If you do not know all of the possible Name values ahead of time, you can use a dynamic pivot. Conditional aggregation may also be an option.

Looks like a pivot to me too. Why not merge the same dates for different bobs into one row though?

T N - yes they can be in the same date row.

As for knowing the name values, I am looking to make this dynamic, so new name = new column.

This might help you get started https://dbfiddle.uk/pbgtdVRV

That works, thank you, I was hoping to be able to make the names expand as new people were added, but as it's just the 2 of us this works great.
Thanks again.
